# Using regex to capture text between "^1234:" and ", ^5678:"

Tags: regex, re2

I'm trying to create a regex query to extract everything between the characters

```
^1234:
```

and

```
, ^5678:
```

I tried the following and it doesn't work. Am i on the right track?

```
^(\^1234),(\^5678)$
```

Example text:

```
54:16812344266, ^1234:iwantthistext, ^5678:idontwantthis, ^0000: idontwantthiseither
```

Comment: Depends on the tool you're using too. You likely want a capture group to pick the part in between those two markers. In the regex you have, nothing is allowed in between (well except the comma, if we count that)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `sed`, you can do something like this:

```
$ echo '54:16812344266, ^1234:iwantthistext, ^5678:idontwantthis, ^0000: idontwantthiseither' | sed 's/.*\^1234:\(.*\), \^5678.*/\1/'
iwantthistext
```

You want to use the `()` to capture the match in between the strings. Then replace the full value with the capture text.

The first `.*` will match everything before `^1234` and the second `.*` will match everything after `^5678`. The `^` needs escaping with a backslash so `sed` doesn't use it for interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: `\^1234(.*?), \^5678`

With input `54:16812344266, ^1234:iwantthistext, ^5678:idontwantthis, ^0000: idontwantthiseithere` will output:

https://regex101.com/r/22Fplx/1